# In $\mathbf{Sets}^\mathbf{Q}$, prove the subobject classifier $\Omega$ is given by $\Omega(q)=\{r\mid r\in\mathbf{R^+},r\ge q\}.$

Tags: category-theory, rational-numbers, topos-theory, functors

This is **Exercise I.9** of Mac Lane and Moerdijk's, *"Sheaves in Geometry and Logic [. . .]"*.

### The Details:

A definition of a subobject classifier is given on page 32, *ibid.*

> **Definition:** In a category $\mathbf{C}$ with finite limits, a *subobject classifier* is a monic, ${\rm true}:1\to\Omega$, such that to every monic $S\rightarrowtail X$ in $\mathbf{C}$ there is a unique arrow $\phi$ which, with the given monic, forms a pullback square
>
> $$\begin{array}{ccc}
> S & \to & 1 \\
> \downarrow & \, & \downarrow {\rm true}\\
> X & \stackrel{\dashrightarrow}{\phi} & \Omega.
> \end{array}$$

### The Question:

> Let $\mathbf{Q}$ be the (linearly) ordered set of all rational numbers considered as a category, while $\mathbf{R^+}$ is the set of reals with a symbol $\infty$ adjoined. In $\mathbf{Sets}^\mathbf{Q}$, prove that the subobject classifier $\Omega$ has $\Omega(q) = \{r \mid r\in \mathbf{R^+}, r \ge q\}$.

### Context:

I have asked about an example of a subobject classifier in the past:

- [Understanding an example of a subobject classifier.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/600110/104041)

But that was a long time ago and with a subtle difference in the definition of a subobject classifier.

You can check my recent questions for how to show some subobject classifiers do not exist.

I'm studying topos theory for fun and **Exercise I.9** is exciting to me because the truth values of $\mathbf{Sets}^\mathbf{Q}$ (*i.e.*, $\Omega(q)$ in the question, right?) make sense to me intuitively (no pun intended).

### My Attempt:

The terminal object in $\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{Q}}$ is, I suppose, $1_{\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{Q}}}:\mathbf{Q}\to \textbf{Sets} $ given by $1_{\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{Q}}}(s)=\{\ast\}$ for a rational number $s$; I'm not sure how to prove this.

Let $p:\mathbf{Q}\to \mathbf{Sets}$ and $q:\mathbf{Q}\to \mathbf{Sets}$ be objects in $\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{Q}}$. Suppose $f: p\rightarrowtail q$ is a monic natural transformation in $\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{Q}}$.

We have $!_s: s\to 1_{\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{Q}}}$ given by (again, I suppose) $!_s: s(\rho)\mapsto \ast$ for all $\rho\in \Bbb Q$ and all $s\in {\rm Ob}(\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{Q}})$.

Let $\Omega\in{\rm Ob}(\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{Q}})$ be as defined in the question.

> How do we define $(\phi=)\chi_f:q\dashrightarrow \Omega$ and ${\rm true}: 1_{\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{Q}}}\to \Omega$?

I get that, by definition of a pullback, I need, for $x\in{\rm Ob}(\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{Q}})$ and $h: x\to q$ with ${\rm true}\circ !_x=\chi_f\circ h$, the existence of a unique $x\stackrel{u}{\dashrightarrow}p$ in ${\rm Mor}(\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{Q}})$ such that $f\circ u=h$ and $!_p\circ u=!_x$.

Please help :)

Comment: Surely you mean $p: \mathbb Q \rightarrow \textbf{Sets}$ and $q: \mathbb Q \rightarrow \textbf{Sets}$? Since objects of $\textbf{Sets}^{\mathbb Q}$ are functors $\mathbb Q \rightarrow \textbf{Sets}$

Comment: Well, @NoelLundström, $\mathbf{Q}$, as opposed to $\Bbb Q$, has the extra property that it is assumed to be linearly ordered. Since an object of $\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{Q}}$ is a functor from $\mathbf{Q}\to \mathbf{Sets}$, it is, I suppose, like I said, a function from $\mathbf{Q}$ to some set in $\mathbf{Sets}$, right? I'm not saying you're wrong; I'm just trying to make clear my reasoning.

Comment: Yes I meant $\textbf Q$ instead of $\mathbb Q$, the distinction is irrelevant. But no a functor $\mathbf Q \rightarrow \textbf{Set}$ is not a function from $\mathbf Q$ to a set. A functor $F:\textbf Q \rightarrow \textbf{Set}$ is a way to assign every rational number $s$ to a set $Fs$ together with a function $Fs \rightarrow Fs'$ whenever $s' \leq s $. You might be confusing $\textbf{Sets}^\mathbf Q$ with the slice category $\mathbf Q / \textbf{Sets}$ where objects are arrows $\mathbf Q \rightarrow X$ for a set $X$.

Comment: Ah, yes; of course! Let me correct my work so far, then, in an edit. Thank you, @NoelLundström.

Comment: Is that better, @NoelLundström?

Comment: Yes that is better :) I made an edit to the part about the terminal object aswell that you missed.

Comment: Do you know what the subobject classifier is in general in a presheaf category $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf{C}}$?  If so, then you should hopefully be able to apply it in this specific case and see why you get something isomorphic to the given presheaf.

Comment: I could look it up in Goldblatt's, *"Topoi: [. . .]"* at the very least, @DanielSchepler; thank you. I find that book more comfortable than most on the subject. Perhaps I'll ask another question on here at a later date confirming the details of my understanding and incorporating Noel Lundström's responses. I don't want to fall foul of the Dunning-Kruger effect.

Comment: On thinking about it, I wonder if the result should actually look more like subsets of $\mathbb{R}^+ \sqcup \mathbb{Q}$, with one copy of each rational number being "infinitesimally" greater than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trick to calculating subobject classifiers (if they exist) in a functor category $\textbf{Sets}^\textbf C$. Namely if we denote by $h_c=\text{Hom}(c,-):\textbf C \rightarrow \textbf{Sets}$ we know by the yoneda lemma that if $\Omega$ exists $$\text{Sub}(h_c) = \text{Nat}(h_c , \Omega) = \Omega(c)$$

then you can try and figure out what a subobject of $h_c$ looks like. A hint would be that monomorphisms in a functor category $\text{Func}(C,D)$ are precisely the natural transformations which are pointwise monomorphisms, i.e $\phi:F \rightarrow G$ is a monomorphism iff $\phi_c$ is a monomorphism for all $c$.

The terminal object $T$ in a functor category is given by the functor $T$ which takes every object $c$ in $C$ to the terminal object in $D$.