# Can the statements about future be proposition?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, philosophy

i am confused with not happened statement whether they are proposition or not.For example , if i say that "tomorrow there will be an earthquake in Canada".Can we say that it is a proposition because it will be either true or false.However it hasnt happened yet.Can you enlight me please?

Comment: There is a topos for "time until truth". See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/600110/104041).

Comment: The short answer is "yes"; the long answer is "yes, unless you're persuaded otherwise by certain philosophical complaints". But in mathematics, there's no time anyway.

Comment: See [Future Contingents](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/future-contingents/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proposition is defined as a declarative sentence that is either True or False, but not both. So, yes, a proposition is $1+1=2$, or $7$ is even. The first one is true, the second one is false.

Sometimes a sentence does not provide enough information to determine whether it is True or False, so it is not a proposition. For example "he is a mathematician". But if you say "Peter Scholze is a mathematician", then it is a proposition.

Does this applies to your example? Do we have enough information to decide whether or not there will be an earthquake in Canada tomorrow?
As you see, this depends very much on the context. We haven't enough context here to decide this.

Answer (score 0):

A cautious geologist might report something like, "Based recent seismic data, our computer models show a high probability of a significant earthquake in Canada within the next 24 hours." That would be logical proposition that could be immediately verified. That is not this case with your original statement above.