# Does there exist a topos with these $n+2$ truth values?

Tags: logic, dynamical-systems, philosophy, topos-theory, intuitionistic-logic

This question is based on the answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/600110/104041) question.

### The Question:

Let $n\in\Bbb N$. Let $N$ be a set with $n+2$ elements, labelled $0$ to $n$, and the $(n+2)$th element labelled $\infty$. Suppose we have a function

$$\begin{align}
t:N &\to N,\\
0 &\mapsto 0,\\
m &\mapsto m-1,\quad\text{(for } m\in \overline{1,n}\text{)}\\
\infty &\mapsto \infty.
\end{align}$$

Does there exist a topos whose internal logic corresponds to $\infty$ being "false", $0$ being "true", and each $m\in \overline{1,n}$ being "$m$ steps (through $t$) until truth"?

### Motivation:

An answer to this question, hopefully, will kill two birds with one stone: objections to: (1) systems of logic with more than two truth-values and (2) whether infinity has a rigorous place in mathematics.

### Thoughts:

It is my belief that such a topos can be created; however, I don't know how.

I'm aware that $(N, t)$ is a [dynamical system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20dynamical%20system,each%20springtime%20in%20a%20lake.). I don't have much experience with them.

For an idea of my abilities in topos theory, see this: [The legitimacy of topos theory and intuitionism.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3608399/104041)

Please help :)

Comment: I don't know what role you want $t$ to have in the topos.  You can certainly find a topos whose truth values are a totally ordered set with $n+2$ elements but I don't know what "$m$ steps until truth" is supposed to mean in a topos.

Comment: Here $t$ is intended to play an analogous role to that of $p$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/600212/104041), @EricWofsey.

Comment: What's the first thing about $t$ that is not clear? Have I misled people with the wrong choice of symbol for the set currently denoted by $\Omega$? It seems like you understand, @EricWofsey, what I'm aiming for with your example of a topos with a totally ordered set of $n+2$ truth values. Perhaps you could elaborate on that in an answer. I hope this post is not a silly question.

Comment: I've edited the "$m$ steps until truth" to "$m$ steps (through $t$) until truth", @EricWofsey.

Comment: As Eric says, you can certainly find a topos whose truth values are a totally ordered set with $n + 2$ elements, and like Eric I have no idea what "$m$ steps until truth" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Let me jump on that train: I don't get the role of $t$ and "$m$ steps until truth" either.

Comment: I don't understand what the difficulty is, since "sets through time" as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/600110/104041) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/600212/104041) are clear enough, where $t$ in the question corresponds to $p$, @QiaochuYuan.

Comment: @Shaun: that question is about a specific topos of functors $\omega \to \mathbb{N}$. Your question is about an arbitrary topos; what is $t$ supposed to be in that context? Do you want the topos to be equipped with an endomorphism? What kind of endomorphism?

Comment: Consider the white king in chess, moving forward at each step when it has a clear path from [e1 to e8](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)#:~:text=Each%20square%20of%20the%20chessboard,to%20right%20(the%20kingside%20).) the other side of the board. Then at first: the truth of "the white king is at a1" is false, so corresponds to $\infty$, or "never true", and the truth of "the white king is at e8" is $7$, so $t$ corresponds to making the white king move. Do you see what I mean, @QiaochuYuan? (I'm sorry if I appear impatient; I really want to understand this.)

Comment: @Shaun: I do not understand what would constitute an answer to your question. If I gave you an example of a topos $T$ and a logical functor $F : T \to T$ whose set of truth values $\text{Hom}(1, \Omega)$  is isomorphic to your poset $N$ and such that the induced map $F : \text{Hom}(1, \Omega) \to \text{Hom}(1, \Omega)$ is $t$, or proved that no such pair $(T, F)$ existed, would that answer your question? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: Yes, I believe that would answer my question, @QiaochuYuan. I'm sorry about any ambiguity.

Comment: (When I say I believe it would answer my question, @QiaochuYuan, I mean that, as far as I can tell, it makes sense in that the words look arranged in an appropriate manner, but, as yet, I do not understand it; I will leave the job of explaining it to you (or whoever wants to answer that way).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you read *SGL* by MacLane and Moerdijk (available [here](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/SMIM.pdf)) since I'm going to be quoting results from there and generally it's a great introduction to Topos theory.

In particular, in I.4 we are given the following characterisation for the subobject classifier of a presheaf topos ${\bf Sets}^{\mathcal{C}^{op}}$:
$$ \Omega\colon \mathcal{C}^{op} \to {\bf Sets}, \ \ \Omega(C) = \{\,S \mid S \text{ is a sieve on $C$}\,\}.$$
In the text, they offer one motivating description of $\Omega(C)$ as "the set of "paths to truth"".  The map ${\rm true} \colon 1 \to \Omega$ has as components $\ast \mapsto t_C$ (where $t_C$ is the maximal sieve of all arrows to $C$).

We might want to restrict to when $\mathcal{C}$ is a preorder category, in which case sieves correspond to down-sets in the order.  If $\alpha$ is an ordinal, the nonempty down-sets of $\alpha^{op}$ are in bijection with the elements of $\alpha$. *In some sense* these are the "truth values".  For a subfunctor $Q \rightarrowtail P$ in ${\bf Sets}^{\alpha^{op}}$, the characteristic map $\varphi^Q \colon P \to \Omega$ has components $\varphi^Q_\beta(x) = \gamma$, the least ordinal $\gamma \in \alpha$ such that $x\cdot f \in Q(\gamma)$ (where $f$ is the map induced by $\beta \leqslant \gamma$), or $\varphi^Q_\beta(x) = \bot$ should such a $\gamma$ not exist.

It's not hard to see that, taking $\alpha = n$, we get the topos you seek.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have a paperback copy of *SGL*.  The exercises are much more challenging to me than those of *Topoi: A Categorial Analysis of Logic*, at least to start with; much more category theory is assumed in *SGL*. I have no formal training in category theory, let alone topos theory.

Comment: Yes, category theory is necessary.  I can also suggest Eugenia Cheng's videos for an intro to category theory: https://www.youtube.com/user/TheCatsters/featured